# Autofac - resolve before build

Tags: c#, autofac

With Unity dependency can be resolved before the container is build. Is that possible with Autofac as well?
Below code demonstrates my scenario - I'd need to resolve the `ICacheRepository` in order to "new up" the singleton `CacheHelper`.

In Unity that would be simply done with `container.Resolve<ICacheRepository>()` in the place of ???. What about in Autofac?

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<CacheRepository>().As<ICacheRepository>();
var cacheHelper = new CacheHelper(???);
builder.RegisterInstance(cacheHelper).As<CacheHelper>();
```

Where `CacheHelper` class has a constructor dependency on `CacheRepository`.

```
public class CacheHelper
{
    private readonly ICacheRepository _repository;

    public CacheHelper(ICacheRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your goal to make `cacheHelper` a singleton? This can be achieved in another way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not have to resolve component during build process. *Autofac*  is able to solve object graph dependency. In your case `CacheHelper` depends on `ICacheRepository` so you just have to register `CacheHelper` and `ICacheRepository`

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<CacheRepository>().As<ICacheRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<CacheHelper>().As<CacheHelper>();
```

When *Autofac* will resolve `CacheHelper` it will create the dependency graph and create the instance of `CacheHelper` with an instance ofsi  `ICacheRepository`. If you need to have a *Singleton* you can tell Autofac to create only a single instance.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<CacheRepository>().As<ICacheRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<CacheHelper>().As<CacheHelper>().SingleInstance();
```

Another solution would be register lambda expression, these registrations are called when you need it, so you can *resolve* things during build process :

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<CacheRepository>().As<ICacheRepository>();
builder.Register(c => new CacheHelper(c.Resolve<ICacheRepository>()))
       .As<CacheHelper>()
       .SingleInstance(); // It will result of having one CacheHelper whereas 
                          // ICacheRepository is declared as .InstancePerDependency
```

Be careful with this solution because `ICacheRepository` is declared without scope the `InstancePerDependency` scope will be used by default. Because `CacheHelper` is `SingleInstance` only a single instance of `ICacheRepository` will be used which may result to bugs. See [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) for more information.

In your case, it doesn't seem like you need this kind of registration.

Comment: Do note that in your last two examples, the `CacheRepository` becomes a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) of the `CacheHelper` which often results in bugs.

Comment: @Steven : nice catch, didn't see it while writing my answer. I edited my post. Thanks.

Comment: It's easy to overlook. That's why containers should have built-in detection for this kind of stuff.