# Autofac. Resolve a dependency for a Func during the build process

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a class which takes a `Func` as a constructor argument:

```
public CurrencyCache(Func<IEnumerable<Currency>> loadData)
```

The `Func` is basically the method to call when the cache has expired

When I register this in AutoFac I need to specify the method. And to do that I need to resolve a dependency from the container. Except I can’t as the container isn’t built yet

```
builder.Register(o => new CurrencyCache(<some code to resolve the class with the method I want to call>));
```

I don’t want to manually new-up the dependency graph to this class as it is a few levels deep and needs various data from config files etc

So I want the container to resolve the class for me

But as I say, the container isn’t built yet

Is there a way around this? Does Autofac have some api to deal with such a scenario

Comment: are you searching a way to resolve `Interface` before `ContainerBuilder` is build ? Try [Autofac - resolve before build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500858/autofac-resolve-before-build)

Comment: just looking for a way to register a class that takes a Func. similar to this I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583339/autofac-and-func-factories . but not quite the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `Register` method with a lambda arguments, the first parameter is a `IComponentContext` which is a builded container.

You can do this :

```
builder.Register(o => new CurrencyCache(o.Resolve<XXX>().DoSomething));
```

By the way be careful with the scope of registration to avoid [captive dependency issue](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).